How to select multiple GIS regions in AnyLogic source block?
I have a GIS workspace, where I have 4 zipcodes. People are set in random location of each zipcode. I have just one facility (pharmacy). Now I want to measure the queue size, utilization and time in system. For that, I have created a process flow, In the source block, Location of arrival I chose 'Network / GIS node', below that in Node, I can choose only one zipcode (gis region), but I have 4 gis regions. How can I choose all of them? See the attached picture of GIS space, process flow, and properties of source block.


pls only use the anylogic tag, else other SOF users get confused :)

Sure. Thank you so much Benjamin. Its now working perfectly.

Incase if I want to limit the number of people in each zip code, how to do that? Say, Zip 1, 2, 3, 4 has 100, 150, 200, 175, 90 people respectively? should I post a separate question for this?

pls always open new issues (with full details) for new questions, SOF does not work like a back-n-forth forum but is a pure Q&A place, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow


How can I choose all of them?

You can not, and it would not make sense, if you think about it.
What you can do is to select a random from those 4, effectively this is the same outcome as choosing "all".
First, add all 4 regions into a collection (select them, right-click -> add to collection).
Then, switch the "Node" selection from the drop-down to the code-based entry (the small icon to the left of the drop-down).
In the now appearing code field, write randomFrom(myCollectionOfGISRegions)
Now each new agent will be put into 1 of the 4 regions
